# UwAmp doesn't recognize Apache or MySQL as started

Tags: uwamp

I updated Apache, replaced the old MySQL version with MariaDB and updated PHP to 8.1 in UwAmp. Everything works fine, except the fact that UwAmp doesn't recognize Apache or MariaDB as running. It shows stopped for both:

[image]

But when I check the processes, `mysqld.exe` and `httpd.exe` are running. Does anyone know what to enable/activate or how UwAmp recognizes if Apache or MysQL / MariaDB are running? It doesn't detect it by the process name, isn't it?